# 2001 Nissan Sentra will not pass 2000 RPM in drive

Tags: nissan, rpm, sentra

I have a 2001 nissan sentra. When I am in park, the engine RPM struggles, but eventually rises up past 2k to 5k or wherever I let it off. However, when it is in gear(drive, reverse, 1st, 2nd) it will not pass 2k RPM. It does not have any codes, so I am not sure about it being in limp mode. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What test besides checking for codes have you done? Sounds like it may have a intake/exhaust restriction

Comment: @cano Just a bunch of dead end checking. Making sure sensors are in tact, fuses, etc. How could that be indicative of a restriction to the intake/exhaust if in park it isn't limited to the 2k rpm, only in gear?

Comment: Did this happen suddenly? Or has it been getting progressively worse? How many miles are on this engine? Sounds like it may be worn out or have excessive wear. I would suggest you do a compression check.

Comment: Try pulling the upstream o2 sensor, see if it helps. If it doesn't you know it's not an exhaust restriction. I assume it's not misfiring? How do fuel trims look?

Comment: @CharlieRB Unfortunately, this vehicle was aquired in this state. About 160k on it.

Comment: @Ben I'll give that a go. No misfires. Haven't checked fuel trims, as I currently am not with the vehicle. Any idea what it should be running?